# MySQL pivot data

Tags: mysql

I have data.

```
   A,   STATUS,  P
   A1,    1,     P1
   A1,    1,     P2
   A1,    1,     P3
   A2,    1,     P3
   A2,    1,     P4
   A2,    1,     P5
   A3,    0,     NULL
```

I want result same

```
   P,   A1,  A2,  A3
   P1,  1,   0,   0
   P2,  1,   0,   0
   P3,  1,   1,   0
   P4,  0,   1,   0
   P5,  0,   1,   0
```

How can I do it with mysql query?

Comment: How many distinct `A` values are in your case?

Comment: A value is dynamic value. auto distinct when move from row to column.

Answer (score 3):

Try this;)

```
select
    `P`,
    max(if(`A` = 'A1', `STATUS`, 0)) as `A1`,
    max(if(`A` = 'A2', `STATUS`, 0)) as `A2`,
    max(if(`A` = 'A3', `STATUS`, 0)) as `A3`
from table1
where `P` IS NOT NULL
group by `P`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2fa3e/3)

**Edited:**

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`A` = ''',
      `A`,
      ''', `STATUS`, 0)) AS ',
      `A`
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `P`, ', @sql, ' FROM table1 WHERE `P` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `P`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2fa3e/6)**

Comment: A1, A2, A3 is dynamic value

Comment: @ChauApple For dynamic value, check edited answer please.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the maximum number of potential columns, you can pivot your results using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select p, 
       max(case when a = 'A1' then status else 0 end) a1,
       max(case when a = 'A2' then status else 0 end) a2,
       max(case when a = 'A3' then status else 0 end) a3
from yourtable
group by p
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/023712/1)

If you don't know the number of potential columns, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` instead.